# Wep Api Sign In After Facebook Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, authentication, oauth-2.0

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31161854/after-external-login-success-need-to-generate-token-response-for-application) that was poorly phrased and didn't generate a response.  So I thought I'd simplify my question.

In my web api, I need to sign the user into my application after facebook tells me they're authenticated.  If I had my own OAuth server I'd do:

```
OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
{
    AllowInsecureHttp = true,
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
    Provider = new AuthorizationServerProvider(container.Resolve<IAuthenticationRepository>())
};

app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
```

which allows the user to login at my `/token` endpoint.  I don't want to expose the `/token` endpoint, as I'm only using external logins, but I need to hook into my OAuthServerProvider.  I'd like to generate a token from the server side, after facebook authenticates them.  How can I hook into my own OAuthServerProvider for a token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a working solution.  First, I needed to add `BearerAuthentication` to my application in `Startup`:

```
public class Startup
{
    public static OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions OAuthBearerOptions { get; private set; }

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
       //other code

       OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions();
       app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions); 

       OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();
       app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions);

       //other code
    }
```

Like I said, I don't want an endpoint available to get a token for the client, as I'm the only one requesting tokens, when a user is authenticated via facebook.  So my `OAuthServerOptions` doesn't declare a value for `TokenEndpoint`

Then, when I authenticated a user with facebook, and was ready to issue them a token, I used my `OAuthBearerOptions` to generate a token from an `AuthenticationTicket`:

```
var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);
var accessToken = Startup.OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);
```

Here's the whole method to generate a response with a token (taken from the great blog [BitOfTech](http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/))

```
private JObject GenerateLocalAccessTokenResponse(string userName)
{
    var tokenExpiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);

    ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName));
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

    var props = new AuthenticationProperties()
    {
        IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
        ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(tokenExpiration),
    };

    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);
    var accessToken = Startup.OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);

    JObject tokenResponse = new JObject(
                            new JProperty("userName", userName),
                            new JProperty("access_token", accessToken),
                            new JProperty("token_type", "bearer"),
                            new JProperty("expires_in", tokenExpiration.TotalSeconds.ToString()),
                            new JProperty(".issued", ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc.ToString()),
                            new JProperty(".expires", ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc.ToString())
                            );

     return tokenResponse;
}
```

Now I have a token ready for the client to consume.